# How to access secure actuator endpoints without adding spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Actuator "sensitive" endpoints secure since 1.5.x version, is it possible to specify user in properties or yml file and access these endpoints without adding spring security into project?
I know that there's property management.security.enabled can be set to false to expose endpoints, but want to keep them secure:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. 
Just add the below lines in src/main/resources/application.properties file.

```
management.security.enabled=true 
security.user.name=admin  
security.user.password=admin1  
management.security.roles=SUPERUSER
```

After this, add below dependency in your application pom.xml file.

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Restart your application and try to access any sensetive actuator. You will be prompted to enter username and password. Enter the username and password that you configured in application.priperties.
After entering you will be able to access the sentive actuators.
Hope this helps.
Happy coding

Comment: Just alittle tweak required `security.user.name=admin  
security.user.password=admin1` use `spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin1` for Spring 2.x.x